# service not listening on port from hosting.json

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is my Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                //.UseUrls("http://*:50000")
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

I have a hosting.json as follows.

```
{
  "server.urls": "http://*:5011"
}
```

My project.json contains following

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config",
      "NLog.config",
      "hosting.json"
    ]
  }
```

However when I run it either from within Visual Studio or outside of VS (just by launching the executable), I see following

> Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

Why it's not using port 5011 as in the hosting.json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the ConfigurationBuilder, but you are not using it. You can use the configuration builder like this - .UseConfiguration(config). Here is the modified code.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```